# How to count multiple values from a file in python

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

i have a file 'test.txt' which look likes:

```
emma 5
peter 9
emma 2
peter 10
peter 7
aps 25
emma 1
```

then i should somehow summ the values with the same key so the answer is:

```
aps 25
emma 8
peter 26
```

i managed to write a code

```
d = {}
with open('game.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       if key in d:
           d[key].append(val)

       else:
           d[key] = [val]
for x, v in d.items():
    print (x,v)
```

but it gives me:

```
aps ['25']
peter ['9', '10', '7']
emma ['5', '2', '1']
```

so i can't summ the values together. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: just use a number as the value, why are you using a list? just put the number in, keep adding to it. convert to int first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't sum the values because they are strings. You will be able to sum them if you convert them to integers:

   ```
   for x, v in d.items():
       print(x, sum(int(val) for val in v))
   ```
2. You can shorten your code by using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

   ```
   from collections import defaultdict

   d = defaultdict(int)

   with open('game.txt') as f:
       for line in f:
          key, val = line.split()
          d[key] += int(val)

   for x, v in d.items():
       print (x, v)
   ```

   By using `defaultdict(int)` you don't need to check if the key already exists in the dictionary. If it doesn't exist it will be added and be given value of `0`.

Comment: Replacing *defaultdict* by *Counter* is minimally better, since initialization of *d* then needs no argument and the name makes quite clear, that  integers are handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can make directly to a regular dictionary, like this:

```
d = {}
with open('game.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, value = line.split()
        d[name] = d.get(name, 0) + int(value)

for x, v in d.items():
    print (x, v)
```